# bash как переместить файлы с одинаковыми именами в директорию

Tags: bash

имеется несколько папок `/dir1/`, `/dir2/`, `/dir/`, в каждой лежат файлы `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`

Как мне переместить эти файла в папку `/destination/` чтобы файлы с одинаковыми именами не затерлись?

---

ВАЖНО! Чтобы после расширения файлов не было других символ, например:

`file1.txt, file1.txt~` - не пойдет

`file1.txt, file1~.txt` - примерно то, что надо

Comment: 1. ну, добавьте в начало имени файла имя каталога. будут уникальные имена. 2. для справки: «расширений» у **имён** файлов не существует. они канули в лету вместе с то ли самыми первыми версиями fat-а, то ли даже ещё их предшественника (уже не помню точно). с тех пор у файлов есть **просто имя** (ну, да, в котором могут встретиться и точки, например). даже в fat. не говоря уж про более прогрессивные файловые системы, в которых отродясь ничего подобного даже и не было.

Comment: можете прислать пример команды для командной строки?

Comment: в общем виде так: `for n in файлы; mv $n куда; done`. для каждого файла надо формировать новое имя. basename/dirname вам в помощь.

Comment: к сожалению, я ищу точное решение, а не псевдокод. Гипотетически, я знаю как решать задачу. На практике - не хватает скила работы с bash

Comment: 1. я привёл не псевдокод, а полностью работоспособную команду. вам всего лишь надо вписать свои значения и дополнить формированием желаемого имени. 2. ваш вопрос слишком узок, потому ответ вряд ли будет полезен хоть кому-либо кроме вас. вот если бы вы переформулировали вопрос так, чтобы ответ на него теоретически мог ещё кому-нибудь пригодиться…

Comment: во! вам же ведь в принципе подойдёт и просто смена слэшей на что-нибудь другое. на символ подчёркивания, например: `v=бла/бла/бла; echo ${v//\//_}`. так что можно и без basename/dirname обойтись.